# How Pig's COGROUP operator works?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

How does the COGROUP operator works here?
How and why we are getting empty bag in the last two lines of output(No website explained in details about the data arrangement in COGROUP) ?

```
A = load 'student' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = load 'student' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
dump B;
(joe,18,2.5)
(sam,,3.0)
(bob,,3.5)

X = cogroup A by age, B by age;
dump X;
(18,{(joe,18,2.5)},{(joe,18,2.5)})
(,{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)},{})
(,{},{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)})
```

Comment: is this the actual data set and code that you are using that give nulls?  If not please give samples

Comment: This is the actual example taken from [http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html]

Comment: Why does this have a `Hive` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very clear example in **Definitive Guide book**. I hope the below snippet helps you to understand the cogroup concept.

**grunt> DUMP A;**

(2,Tie)
(4,Coat)
(3,Hat)
(1,Scarf)

**grunt> DUMP B;**

(Joe,2)
(Hank,4)
(Ali,0)
(Eve,3)
(Hank,2)

**grunt> D = COGROUP A BY $0, B BY $1;**

**grunt> DUMP D;**

**(0,{},{(Ali,0)})**

**(1,{(1,Scarf)},{})**

**(2,{(2,Tie)},{(Joe,2),(Hank,2)})**

**(3,{(3,Hat)},{(Eve,3)})**

**(4,{(4,Coat)},{(Hank,4)})**

COGROUP generates a tuple for each unique grouping key. The first field of each tuple
is the key, and the remaining fields are bags of tuples from the relations with a matching
key. The first bag contains the matching tuples from relation A with the same key.
Similarly, the second bag contains the matching tuples from relation B with the same
key.

**If for a particular key a relation has no matching key, then the bag for that relation is
empty.** For example, since no one has bought a scarf (with ID 1), the second bag in the
tuple for that row is empty. This is an example of an outer join, which is the default
type for COGROUP.

Comment: As per the rule, **If for a particular key a relation has no matching key, then the bag for that relation is empty**, where as in my case the relation A, **(sam,,3.0)** second field has empty field that has equivalent empty field in relation B. So the output should be like **(,{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)},{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)})**, but why we are getting **(,{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)},{})**.